# CakePHP4 - How to use the 'RequestHandler' component within another component

Tags: cakephp-4.x, requesthandler

The PHP code segment of my component is shown below:

```
...
class NewsletterFormComponent extends Component {

public $components = ['Flash','RequestHandler'];
public $controller;


public function beforeFilter()
{
$this->controller = $this->getController();
}

public function registration($data = null) {
...
if ($this->request->is('post')) {
//do something
}
...
}
...
```

The following error is displayed:
**Call to a member function is() on null**
How to solve this problem?

Comment: You've loaded the RequestHandler component, but are trying to access a Request object, not RequestHandler.

Comment: Thank you for your reply. How can I access the Request Object within some components?

Comment: The request object is on controllers, not components. But you have access to the controller right there. `$this->controller->request->...`.

Comment: if ($this->controller->getRequest()->is('post')) ---- thanks, this is the solution